# iterate over boost::property_tree XML

Tags: c++, boost

How can i iterate over boost::property_tree (XML part) if i don't know anything about settings structure?

I want to know names of all fields and xmlattr names.

I don't see such example in boost docs for this library.

Answer (score 0):

Check the boost documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html). Part way down the page you can see this example code:

```
// Iterate over the debug.modules section and store all found
// modules in the m_modules set. The get_child() function
// returns a reference to the child at the specified path; if
// there is no such child, it throws. Property tree iterators
// are models of BidirectionalIterator.
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v,
        pt.get_child("debug.modules"))
    m_modules.insert(v.second.data());
```

Simply modify the code to iterate over all of the modules in your root property tree (and recurse into sub-trees if you would like).

So for instance:

```
ptree my_tree;
// Read in your XML to the tree
...
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v,
     pt, do_something_with_field(v.second.data());
```